# Bootstrap 4 requiring individual jQuery Plugins - Uncaught ReferenceError: Util is not defined

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 alpha.  Created a modal by referencing individual files, in this case "util.js" and "modal.js".  In opening the modal it throws this exception.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Util is not defined

See fidle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhjk6tg4/

Updated the fiddle, I got it working, it turns out you need to import the "util.js" first.

Note:  I can't find a CDN for bootstrap 4 alpha individual files, so I copied the raw javascript file of modal.js and paste it in the fiddle (javascript).

Comment: Can you post some code or better host it on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is happening because [bootstrap-4](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4), doesn't respect UMD after the version `v4.0.0-alpha.3`. Please, see the explanation and the corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/20072):

> This removes **UMD** and **CommonJS** transpilation from the build.

Therefore an old module formats & loaders/transpilers (AMD+requirejs, CommonJS+browserify, etc), can't be used the old way, as individual UMD files are **not** available [in the directory anymore](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/20072/files).

You would need to update the way you build your JS application, or to use the compiled Bootstrap JS from `/dist`.